# PHP RSS Feed Reader

Tags: javascript, php, xml, rss

I'm trying to set up a rss reader with php. I got this code from w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_rss_reader.asp)

this is the getrss.php page

```
<?php
//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

//find out which feed was selected
if($q=="Google") {$xml=("http://news.google.com/news?ned=us&topic=h&output=rss");}
else if($q=="NBC") {$xml=("http://rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml");}

$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load($xml);

//get elements from "<channel>"
$channel=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('channel')->item(0);
$channel_title=$channel->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_link=$channel->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
$channel_desc=$channel->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;

//output elements from "<channel>"
echo("<p><a href='".$channel_link."'>".$channel_title."</a>");
echo("<br>");
echo($channel_desc."</p>");

//get and output "<item>" elements
$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('item');
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $item_title=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_link=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    $item_desc=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo ("<p><a href='".$item_link."'>".$item_title."</a>");
    echo ("<br>");
    echo ($item_desc."</p>");
}
?>
```

This is the Javascript

```
<script>
function showRSS(str) {
  if (str.length==0) {
    document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {  // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("rssOutput").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getrss.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

And this is the HTML

```
<form>
<select onchange="showRSS(this.value)">
<option value="">Select an RSS-feed:</option>
<option value="Google">Google News</option>
<option value="NBC">NBC News</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="rssOutput">RSS-feed will be listed here...</div>
```

---

Now for some reason, im getting errors on my page like...

Warning: DOMDocument::load(rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml): failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in ..\test\getrss.php on line 10

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "rss.msnbc.msn.com/id/3032091/device/rss/rss.xml" in ..\test\getrss.php on line 10

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in E:\webroot\IIS_Intranet\test\getrss.php on line 13

i've tried looking up to see how i can correct this but have been unsuccessful